# C# detect offline mode (SQL Server connection)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, exception, offline-mode

I am developing a C# application which connects to SQL Server. If the network connection breaks, the application should be able to go into a "read-only mode" (offline mode) and only read data from a local database. Right now, I am trying to figure out how to detect the disconnect:

```
public int executeNonQuery(string query, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
        int result;

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            tryOpenSqlConnection(sqlConnection);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
            {
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                }
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            sqlConnection.Close(); 
        }

        return result;
}

private void tryOpenSqlConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            if (se.Number == 26)
            {
                catchOfflineMode(se);
            }

            throw se;
        }
    }

//...

private void catchOfflineMode(SqlException se)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SqlException: " + se.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Setting offline mode...");

    //...
}
```

I thought about using the SQL error codes to detect the loss of connection. But the problem is that sometimes I get exceptions only after the `SqlConnection` already established, e.g. during execution of the command. The last exception I got was

> Error Code 121 - The semaphore timeout period has expired

So, I would have to check every single error code that could have to do with losing network connection.

**EDIT**: I also thought about catching every `SqlException` and then checking the ethernet connection (e.g. pinging the server) to check whether the exception comes from a lost connection or not.

Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Checking for exceptions on every request is going to cause performance issues. In the book [Dependency Injection in .NET, section 9.2](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) is described a **circuit breaker pattern**, which is specifically meant for supporting "offline mode" and it has a more practical approach than checking for exceptions on every request.

Comment: At the end of the remarks section of `SqlException`: [*So, in general, write an exception handler that catches any provider specific exceptions as well as exceptions from the common language runtime.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and then looking further to what `Number` represents you'll find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number(v=vs.110).aspx) which means you've only scratched the surface of things you have to cater for.

Comment: Thanks NightOwl888, I will have a look at it!

Comment: Hi rene, I know that there are a lot of errors to consider. That's why I'm asking if there is any better way to deal with it. Catching every single exception/error just doesn't seem to be the best way to do it for me. But what about catching the exceptions from a sql query/connection and then checking the connection to the server? If the application is already offline, we don't need to care about the failure rate. At the same time, we make sure that every operation is considered (by checking the connection every time after an exception occurs).

Comment: NightOwl888, I looked at the circuit breaker pattern and used a simple implementation from [here](https://github.com/alexandrnikitin/CircuitBreaker.Net) As you said, the circuit breaker pattern solves the performance issue by tracking the number of failures over a period of time but it does not solve the issue on how to detect a broken network connection. Furthermore, I need to react to failures immediately (if one db call breaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with my own solution by creating a simple helper class called

> ExternalServiceHandler.cs

which is used as a proxy for external service calls to detect the online and offline status of the application after an operation failed.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Application.Utilities;

namespace Application.ExternalServices
{
    class ExternalServiceHandler: IExternalServiceHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler OnlineModeDetected;
        public event EventHandler OfflineModeDetected;

        private static readonly int RUN_ONLINE_DETECTION_SEC = 10;
        private static ExternalServiceHandler instance;
        private Task checkOnlineStatusTask;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
        private Exception errorNoConnection;

        public static ExternalServiceHandler Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ExternalServiceHandler();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        private ExternalServiceHandler()
        {
            errorNoConnection = new Exception("Could not connect to the server.");
        }

        public virtual void Execute(Action func)
        {
            if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

            try
            {
                func();
            }
            catch
            {
                if(offlineModeDetected())
                {
                    throw errorNoConnection;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                } 
            }
        }

        public virtual T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
        {
            if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (offlineModeDetected())
                {
                    throw errorNoConnection;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

            try
            {
                await func();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (offlineModeDetected())
                {
                    throw errorNoConnection;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
        {
            if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

            try
            {
                return await func();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (offlineModeDetected())
                {
                    throw errorNoConnection;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool offlineModeDetected()
        {
            bool isOffline = false;
            if (!LocalMachine.isOnline())
            {
                isOffline = true;
                Console.WriteLine("-- Offline mode detected (readonly). --");

                // notify all modues that we're in offline mode
                OnOfflineModeDetected(new EventArgs());

                // start online detection task
                cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                checkOnlineStatusTask = Run(detectOnlineMode, 
                    new TimeSpan(0,0, RUN_ONLINE_DETECTION_SEC), 
                    cancelSource.Token);
            }
            return isOffline;
        }

        private void detectOnlineMode()
        { 
            if(LocalMachine.isOnline())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-- Online mode detected (read and write). --");

                // notify all modules that we're online
                OnOnlineModeDetected(new EventArgs());

                // stop online detection task
                cancelSource.Cancel();
            }
        }

        public static async Task Run(Action action, TimeSpan period, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(period, cancellationToken);

                if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    action();
                }    
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnOfflineModeDetected(EventArgs e)
        {
            OfflineModeDetected?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        protected virtual void OnOnlineModeDetected(EventArgs e)
        {
            OnlineModeDetected?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The `LocalMachine.isOnline()` method looks like this:

```
namespace Application.Utilities
{
    public class LocalMachine
    {
        // ... //

        public static bool isOnline()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string serveraddress = AppSettings.GetServerHttpAddress();
                    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(serveraddress))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // ... //
}
```

The helper class can be used every time an external service call is made. In the following example, a SQL non query is executed by the ExternalServiceHandler:

```
public async Task<int> executeNonQueryAsync(string query)
{
    return await ExternalServiceHandler.Instance.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        return await DBManager.executeNonQueryAsync(query);
    });
}
```

The solution works fine for me. If you have any better ideas, please let me know.