# How can I know SQL Server connection is lost in C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, dbcontext

I'm writing a C# Winforms application using SQL Server 2017. I connect to the server from the client using a wired connection.

Sometimes, the connection is lost due to some conditions. I want to know **immediately** when the connection is lost.

I can check with

```
db.MyDatabaseContext.DatabaseExists()
```

but I have to trigger some event to fire this code.

I want to listen to the server connection being lost.

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032303/c-sharp-detect-offline-mode-sql-server-connection

Comment: Define "server connection being lost". Are you saying that you have an open connection to sql server from the client and it stays open for the life op the application? If so you need to rethink that. The best practice is to always open a *new* connection at the time you need it and then close it as soon as you are done with it. ado .net will handle connection pooling for you so this is cheap to do.